# How do i test accident detection in zendrive iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, zendrive

I am integrating [zendrive](https://developers.zendrive.com/) in my iOS application for accident detection. I have gone trough their [getting started](https://developers.zendrive.com/docs/ios/) page and integrated the SDK in my app for accident detection. I have also visited their [accident detection](https://developers.zendrive.com/docs/ios/accident-detection/) section and follow the instructions.

My question is: 
After integrating this SDK how would i test this feature ? I mean how do i simulate the accident on my code and test the SDK.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in their newer version of the SDK (3.3.3) they have added a new method for simulating mock accident.

So as per their document

> After setting up the SDK in accident detection mode, you can test your
>   integration using ZendriveTest class. Refer to raiseMockAccident for
>   documentation.

```
#import <Zendrive/ZendriveTest.h>

...
// Ensure SDK is setup in ZendriveAccidentDetectionModeEnabled using 
// [Zendrive setupWithConfiguration:delegate:completionHandler:]

// Raise a mock accident. You can also test your implementations for different confidence levels.


 [ZendriveTest raiseMockAccident:ZendriveAccidentConfidenceHigh];

// On calling above method you will receive processAccidentDetected: callback on your delegate after 5 seconds.
// If you do not receive a callback, look at the logs to figure out possible integration issues.
```

Comment: As of now iOS SDK is already at 4.2.2 and have improved a lot. The way I test the mock accident is by using this `[ZendriveTest raiseMockAccident:ZendriveAccidentConfidenceHigh]` where I immediately send the report to our api. If the confidence value is ZendriveAccidentConfidenceLow then I am bringing up a uialert where I ask user if it is a real detected accident where they can select yes or no.